# How to extract a list from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'd really appreciate some help. I'm stuck on the following problem.

Given the following list of dictionaries:

```
sensors = [{'Index': 0, 'Tub': 0, 'Enable': True},
           {'Index': 1, 'Tub': 0, 'Enable': False},
           {'Index': 2, 'Tub': 0, 'Enable': True},
           {'Index': 0, 'Tub': 1, 'Enable': True},
           {'Index': 1, 'Tub': 1, 'Enable': True},
           {'Index': 2, 'Tub': 1, 'Enable': True}
]
```

How do I create the following list:

```
AvailableSensorsPerTub = [2, 3] # Tub 0 has 2 available sensors, Tub 1 has 3
```

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to do this?

I've tried by doing the following:

1. Create a list of tubs:

```
# Create a list of tubs
tubList = list(set(sensor['Tub'] for sensor in tubLevelSensors))
```

Output is: [0,1]

2. Try and iterate over the list of dictionaries:

```
for tub in tubList:
    for idx in range(len(tubLevelSensors)):
        if tub == tubLevelSensors[idx]['Tub'] and tubLevelSensors[idx]['Enable'] == True:
            print(tubLevelSensors[idx]['Tub'], tubLevelSensors[idx]['Index'])
            print()
```

The following is the output I get:

```
0 0

0 2

1 0

1 1

1 2
```

But from this point onwards I'm stumped on how I get the final result of [3,2].

I'd appreciate anyone's thoughts or suggestions. Many thanks!

Comment: You are already able to print what you need. Instead of printing, you just to count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a list in which each index represents a tub. Then, look at each sensor: increment the count at the tub index by whether the sensor is enabled (`int` + `bool` addition allows us to add a `True`/`False` to an `int`)

```
In [121]: sensors = [{'Index': 0, 'Tub': 0, 'Enable': True},
     ...:            {'Index': 1, 'Tub': 0, 'Enable': False},
     ...:            {'Index': 2, 'Tub': 0, 'Enable': True},
     ...:            {'Index': 0, 'Tub': 1, 'Enable': True},
     ...:            {'Index': 1, 'Tub': 1, 'Enable': True},
     ...:            {'Index': 2, 'Tub': 1, 'Enable': True}
     ...: ]

In [122]: answer = [0]*(1+max(d['Tub'] for d in sensors))

In [123]: answer
Out[123]: [0, 0]

In [124]: for d in sensors:
     ...:     answer[d['Tub']] += d['Enable']
     ...:

In [125]: answer
Out[125]: [2, 3]
```

Comment: You could also take advantage of `int + bool` behavior. False -> 0, True -> 1, so you could choose to write: `answer[d['Tub']] += d['Enable']`

Comment: @flakes: thanks for the suggestion. I'd totally forgotten about that. Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks guys, this works and totally makes sense. I really appreciate this help.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of sensors that have 'Enable' set to True for each 'Tub' value using a dictionary to store the count of available sensors per tub:

```
sensors = [{'Index': 0, 'Tub': 0, 'Enable': True},
           {'Index': 1, 'Tub': 0, 'Enable': False},
           {'Index': 2, 'Tub': 0, 'Enable': True},
           {'Index': 0, 'Tub': 1, 'Enable': True},
           {'Index': 1, 'Tub': 1, 'Enable': True},
           {'Index': 2, 'Tub': 1, 'Enable': True}
]

availableSensorsPerTub = {}

for sensor in sensors:
    if sensor['Enable']:
        # If the sensor is enabled increment count
        tub = sensor['Tub']
        if tub in availableSensorsPerTub:
            availableSensorsPerTub[tub] += 1
        else:
            availableSensorsPerTub[tub] = 1

# convert the dictionary to a list of counts
counts = [availableSensorsPerTub[tub] for tub in availableSensorsPerTub]

print(counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are the minumum and maximum integer ids of the `Tub` values in your records, but you will have to figure it out if you are planning on having the count in a list by matching the element ids.

You can try this one below.

```
mintub, maxtub =  min(x['Tub'] for x in sensors), max(x['Tub'] for x in sensors)
AvailableSensorsPerTub = list(0 for _ in range(mintub, maxtub + 1))
for x in sensors:
    if x['Enable']:
        AvailableSensorsPerTub[x['Tub']] += 1

print(AvailableSensorsPerTub)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to accumulate `Enable` values of each `Tub` to a dictionary and convert it to list

```
from functools import reduce

sensors = [
    {'Index': 0, 'Tub': 0, 'Enable': True},
    {'Index': 1, 'Tub': 0, 'Enable': False},
    {'Index': 2, 'Tub': 0, 'Enable': True},
    {'Index': 0, 'Tub': 1, 'Enable': True},
    {'Index': 1, 'Tub': 1, 'Enable': True},
    {'Index': 2, 'Tub': 1, 'Enable': True}
]

acc_dict = reduce(
    lambda acc, sensor: {
        **acc,
        sensor['Tub']: acc.get(sensor['Tub'], 0) + sensor['Enable']
    },
    sensors,
    {}
)

AvailableSensorsPerTub = [acc_dict[tub] for tub in acc_dict]

print(AvailableSensorsPerTub)
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/uhLSVu)